# PHP Curl authentication followed by redirection

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, curl

Im working on a very simple thing, where i want to first authenticate a user by making a curl call to "http://www.mywebsite.com/login", and if the user is authentic, then redirect the user to that website dashboard i.e "http://www.mywebsite.com/dashboard" 
Now the authentication part goes fine, but when i redirect the user by doing header('location.... it just takes it to the login page, which means the sessionis not there,
following is the code im using

```
$sessionStarted = session_start();

$username= $_POST['Username'];
$password= $_POST['Pass'];
$data = array("username" => "$username", "password" => "$password");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);    
$cookie_file_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie_.txt";   

$ch = curl_init('https://www.mywebsite.com/login');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie_file_path);
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE[ session_name() ]. '; path=/';

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    )                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);      
$decoded = json_decode($result);
if (isset($decoded->result) && $decoded->result == 'ok') 
{

    header("Location: https://www.mywebsite.com/dashboard");
    exit;
}
else 
{      

    header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/?login=fsfailed" );
    exit;

}
```

Comment: can you show us your  json op

Comment: Update: after alot of searching around, i know that the problem that the cookies are not going through, because when you use  "Header(Location...." the cookies you set dont go through, i still havent solved the cookie problem

Comment: Update2: Resolved it by providing the Domain (5th paramter) in setCookie function, apparently my cookies were getting destroyed because i was setting them in one domain and redirecting to another domain.